# How to create a compound view behaving like one component is ViewGroup in layout.xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to build a compound view that has a `ScrollView` and a `LinearLayout` as its base.
Inside that `LinearLayout` there are multiple Views and also an empty layout `ConstraintLayout`, which I want to fill in a layout.xml file.

Example:

CompoundView:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <!-- Some views that come first -->

        <ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/fillableViewGroup">

            <!-- This is the part that I want other Views to be able to fill -->
      
        </ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And I want it to be used like this:

UsingView:

```
<CompoundView>
    <TextView/>
    <TextView/>
    <TextView/>
</CompoundView>
```

So that it behaves like this, including all of the constraints I have defined in `UsingView`:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <!-- Some views that come first -->

        <ConstraintLayout 
            android:id="@+id/fillableViewGroup">
            <TextView/>
            <TextView/>
            <TextView/>
        </ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Is there maybe some function that would allow me to do something like this?:

```
class CompoundView() {
    override fun viewGroupContainer() : ViewGroup {
        return fillableViewGroup
    }
}
```

Or maybe something else that would allow me to assign a ViewGroup to be populated via layout.xml?

I have tried googeling for a solution but basically all I find is tutorials for basic compound views.

PS:
I do understand that I might be able to write a function in the class declaration of my `CompoundView` that would allow me to add a view to one if its children, however, I specifically want it to be able to do so in layout.xml.

Comment: see -> https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question totally but you can include one layout into another. Or can also use <Include> tag in your xml https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan I know how to create a compound view. What I dont know is how to make it behave the way I described.

Comment: @SarahKhan `<include>` allows me to add one layout to another, that is true. However, it does not allow me to add children to the included layout, let alone adding children to a child of that included layout.